# ng-repeat sortBy not reordering after push

Tags: angularjs

As the title says, I can´t achieve the desired behavior when using orderBy with ng-repeat.

That´s the list I want ordered:

```
<div class = 'row' ng-repeat = 'tabla_salarial in master.tablas_salariales | orderBy:-fecha'>
    <div class = 'col'><p><label>{{tabla_salarial.fecha  | date:dd-MM-yyyy }}</label></p></div>
    <div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.salario_bruto | number : 2 }}€</span></p></div>
    <div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.finiquito_vacaciones | number : 2 }}€</span></p></div>
    <div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.finiquito_indemnizacion | number : 2 }}€</span></p></div>
    <div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.precio_sustitucion | number : 2 }}€</span></p></div>
</div>
```

And this is the piece of code inside the controller that is supposed to handle the list insertions:

```
$http.post("controlador/TablaSalarial/insert", $scope.tabla_salarial).then(function(response){
    if ( response.data.errno ){
        Dialog.toast(response.data.err);
    }
    else{
        RowService.add(response.data.row, "tablas_salariales");
        $scope._dialog.hide();
        $scope.t = {};
        $scope.master.tablas_salariales.push(response.data.row);
    }
}, function(response){/*...*/});
```

The table is correctly ordered at start, but every time a push a new record it is appended at the end of the table, although all the other items keep the order.

I know how to make a different approach, or use a new directive, and that´s not what I want.

Is there any way to make it work as expected? (And by expected I mean, keep the list ordered when pushing a new record)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? :)

Comment: Just now: looked, implemented and working ❤(My hero) Thanks for the extra tips

Comment: Pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some mistakes in your code:

1. You should use single quotes in your `orderBy` *filter*:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="tabla_salarial in master.tablas_salariales | orderBy: '-fecha'">
```

2. The `date` *filter* should also have single quotes:

```
<div class="col"><p><label>{{tabla_salarial.fecha  | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</label></p></div>
```

Working **demo**:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [];

    var start = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
    $scope.add = function(times) {
      times = times || 1;
      for (var i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
        $scope.products.push({
          "id": i,
          "expiresOn": new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (new Date().getTime() - start.getTime())),
          "price": parseFloat(Math.min(100 + (Math.random() * (999 - 100)),999))
        });
      }
    }
    
    $scope.add(5);
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <table>
    <caption>Products table</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Expires On</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: '-date'">
        <td ng-bind="product.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="product.expiresOn | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'"></td>
        <td ng-bind="product.price | currency: '€': 2"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" value="add" ng-click="add()">Add new product</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Instead of use the `number` filter and inserting the symbol by hand, as you're doing here for example:

```
<div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.salario_bruto | number : 2 }}€</span></p></div>
```

You can use [**currency**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) *filter* as below:

```
<div class = 'col'><p><span>{{tabla_salarial.salario_bruto | currency: '€': 2" }}</span></p></div>
```

I hope it helps!